# Jquery Mobile Return to Home page

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am working with Jquery Mobile for one of my client's Mobile site (http://restaurants.co.za/mobile)...
The issue as described below:

1. Browse http://restaurants.co.za/mobile
2. Search typing something, say 'a'
3. You will get a list
4. Click on home icon
5. You will return to home page but no functionality of dropdown retain.

Actually The options for dropdown are fetched using PHP as the url changes from http://restaurants.co.za/mobile to something like this "http://restaurants.co.za/mobile/find?restaurant=a&submit=submit-value#&ui-state=dialog" the design gets messed and the functionality get lost.

Is there not any way to just link to http://restaurants.co.za/mobile without using target _blank

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery Mobile links by using AJAX calls, unless you turn it off.

To prevent this default AJAX behavior, you need to specify the following attribute in your anchor/link/button.

```
data-ajax="false"
```

Much more info provided in the jQuery Mobile [Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html).